# Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream every day at same time

Tags: php, nginx

Anyone have an idea why I get

> recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream

Every night at same time, it lasts 10-15 minutes then it goes away. We have plenty of visitors during the day and site works fine.

But every night at same time errors start and site becomes unresponsive.
Not only that but errors in log repeat in same pattern, sometimes every 10 seconds, sometimes 20 sec.

Nginx error log is empty during that time. PHP log has this issues during that time (plenty of those, this is just one example)

```
[18-Jun-2015 22:20:59] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 22250 started  
[18-Jun-2015 22:21:02] WARNING: [pool web1] child 22093, script '/var/www/blabla/web/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") execution timed out (62.994281 sec), terminating  
[18-Jun-2015 22:21:02] WARNING: [pool web1] child 22093 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 63.584813 seconds from start  
[18-Jun-2015 22:21:02] NOTICE: [pool web1] child 22262 started
```

If there is something wrong with my configuration why i dont get any problems during peak hours but in midnight only?

No script is starting during that time in cronjob so it is not that also...

Anyone any idea where to check or what to fix?

Comment: Set-up PHP-FPM status page and fetch it during that time to see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your configuration as of now, but seems like your script is timing out while performing some task,

You should consider changing the nginx config(.conf) file:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_read_timeout  3600;///you can increase this to more

}
```

Comment: Atm i am having in http { 

        fastcgi_send_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;

so you think i should increase them?

Comment: Yes try increasing it.

Comment: Hello again, increasing timeouts did not help. Maybe you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

We found what the problem was. It was JotCache plugin in joomla, starting every day at the same time and doing nasty stuff in mysql.